# winutls for Windows 11 64bit

Tags: python, apache-spark, github, hadoop, windows-11

I have installed a spark cluster on my lapptop of OS windows 11 64 bit and its working smoothly.

While the time of saving dataframe on my local machine i am getting the below error -

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').csv("/Users/sarve/Downloads/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\SPARK\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1864, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "C:\SPARK\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "C:\SPARK\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\SPARK\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.csv.
: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\HADOOP\bin\winutils.exe": CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher
```

code i use to save the file `df.write.mode('overwrite').csv("/Users/sarve/Downloads/")`

github link i use to download the winutils file (which is not compatible as per the error message) - https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

Please let me know what to do

Comment: what is spark version you're using ?

Comment: Spark Version -> 3.5.0